# org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke WARNING: Servlet [] is currently unavailable

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, tomcat9

I have a code in which i am including the backend queries's results from the Servlet to Jsp using session. There are 10 jsp pages that require same functionality with respective servlets. My initial 2 pages worked completely fine but the later ones are giving a hard time even with same code.

The error that is coming is :
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke WARNING: Servlet Gemserver is currently unavailable

in which Gemserver is my Servlet and gem.jsp is the jsp.

Since it is showing Unavailable hence giving me the following error of : java.lang.NullPointerException in jsp

This is for tomcat 9.0 and eclipse .

gem.jsp:

used this to import the servlet's content

```
web.xml:
<!-- GEM -->
     <servlet>
    <br><description></description><br/>
    <servlet-name>Gemserver</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>project.Gemserver</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Gemserver</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Gemserver</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>gem_yr</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>project.gem_yr</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gem_yr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gem_yr</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

THE FULL ERROR:

```
    Jun 25, 2019 7:47:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
WARNING: Servlet [Gemserver] is currently unavailable
Jun 25, 2019 7:47:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/NIC_data] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page [/gem.jsp] at line [306]

303:                       <div class="animated flipInY col-lg-2 col-md-2  col-xs-12">
304:                         <div class="tile-stats">
305:                           
306:                           <div class="count" align="center"><%=status1_total.get(0) %></div>
307: 
308:                           <h2><center>FILLED</center></h2>
309:                         


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.gem_jsp._jspService(gem_jsp.java:435)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1366)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You  are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` check if `status1_total.get(0)` has some value in it or not .